# JAXB: globalBindings in bindings.xml is ignored

Tags: jaxb2

I am trying to generate java files from an XML schema using JAXB. One of the data type in the schema is a string with about 300 possible values. Since this is more than 256, xjc,by default, does not generate an enum for this type but use string instead. Since I want to have enum generated, I create an bindings.xml with the following content:

`<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1000" />
</bindings>`

This does not work for an unknown reason. xjc does not give me any clue. At first I thought that I didn't have the file included so I checked. I also tried to intentionally mispell the element name like `globalBindings` to `globalBinding` and found that xjc complained about the invalid element -- which evidently means that the xjc read the binding file.

However, when I put the globalBindings inside the xsd, it works perfectly -- enum is generated.

`<xs:schema ....>
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1000" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
...
...
</xs:schema >`

So my question is how come the option set in the bingings.xml (which is read by xjc) is not used to customize the compilation? What do I miss here?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 4):

I realized that the length of the current directory causes xjc to ignore the binding configuration.

Executing the following command fails or successes (related to the binding) depending on the base directory of the project:

```
xjc -extension  src/main/resources/schema/schema.xsd -b src/main/resources/schema/bindings.xjb  -d target/tmp
```

So the shorter the project's directory is the more likely it will success:

```
FAILS: C:/anydir/tstaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
FAILS: C:/anydir/tstaaaaaaaa/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
FAILS: C:/anydir/tstaaa/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
FAILS: C:/anydir/tstaa/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
WORKS: C:/anydir/tsta/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
WORKS: C:/anydir/tst/asubdirectory/_this_is_any_project_directory_
```

My colleagues working with a similar environment (also Windows, same JDK, same project sources) do not have such a strict length limitation.
So I have no clue what causes that restriction. But after I located my project sources close to the root directory it worked for me.

Comment: The same for me! I've spent more than a day troubleshooting the issue! It should be accepted as answer

Comment: Does someone reported that issue upstream?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an xjb file not and xml one

Comment: Your answer could be highly enhanced by adding some references and/or examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must add a jaxb annotation before your tags like this:

```
  <jaxb:bindings
      xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
      jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
      jaxb:version="1.0">
        <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="2000"> 
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Um, why?

What's the difference between using "xmlns=..." and "xmlns:jaxb=..." in terms of making the global bindings truly global?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm Achim Tromm's response, the length of the current base directory causes xjc to ignore the binding configuration. Shortening the folder path builds successfully. Is this a JAXB bug!?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue using jax-ws trying to remap BigInteger to Integer with global bindings, but shortening the project path did not work. The solution was to use jaxws namespace specific parent to embed jaxb bindings like following. ([docs](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#standard-customizations))

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            version="2.1"
            wsdlLocation="YOURWSDL.wsdl">

<enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>

<bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='YOURTARGETNAMESPACE']">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        ...
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</bindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this still affects many people but just in case: It seems to have been **fixed since Maven 3.6.1**. We had the exact same problem happening, but only on our build server. Turns out it was still running 3.6.0. Bumping to any version > 3.6.0 fixed the issue for us.